# Why aren't those two expressions semantically equivalent?

Tags: c#

Why does the first test raise a compiler error while the second doesn't? To me they seem semantically equivalent.

```
public bool? inlineTest(bool input)
{
    return input ? null : input;
}

public bool? expandedTest(bool input)
{
    if (input)
        return input;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conditional operator requires both operands to be of the same type. `null` and `bool` aren't compatible, and there's no *automatic* conversion from `bool` to `null`. You need to cast explicitely:

```
return input ? (bool?)input : null;
```

On the other hand, there is an automatic conversion from `bool` to `bool?` and also from `null` to `bool?`, that's why you can return a `bool` and `null` from a `bool?` method.

Comment: Wouldn't the equivalent of expandedTest be `return input ? (bool?)input : null;` ?

Comment: @Fermin: you are right, the logic in the conditions is inverted. I copy-pasted the code from the OP. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

The type inference rules state that:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

So the compiler is able to infer the type if `bool?`.

This type inference doesn't happen in an `if` statement, so it's your job to explicitly state the types.

Answer (score 1):

Both operands should have same data type while using conditional operator.